# How can I find the formula for this table of values?

Tags: excel, math

How can I find the formula for this table of values?

Things I know:

This table horizontally is 45*1.25+(x*0.25) where x is column number starting at 0.

This table vertically is 45*1.25+(y*0.125) where y is row number starting at 0.

These rules only work for the first row and column I believe which is why I'm having an issue figuring out whats going on.

```
56.25   67.5    78.75   90
61.88   78.75   95.63   112.5
67.5    90      112.5   135
```

Comment: Are these the values in excel and do the cells contain teh actual fomulas?

Comment: No, I'm trying to find the formula used to make these with excel. My company received the table but not the formula a long time ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So throwing a regression tool at it, I find a model of

```
56.2513 + 11.2497*x + 5.625*y + 5.625*x*y
```

with parameter standard deviations at

```
0.0017078 0.00091287 0.0013229 0.00070711
```

A measure of the residual errors is 0.0018257, which is down near the rounding error in your data. I would point out that it is quite close to that given by Amadan.

I can get a slightly better model as

```
56.2505 + 11.2497*x + 5.63*y + 5.625*x*y - 0.0025*y^2
```

again, the parameter standard errors are

```
0.0014434 0.00074536 0.0024833 0.00057735 0.001118
```

with a residual error of 0.0013944. The improvement is minimal, and you can see the coefficient of y^2 is barely more than twice the standard deviation. I'd be very willing to believe this parameter does not belong in the model, but was just generated by rounding noise.

Perhaps more telling is to look at the residuals. The model posed by Amadan yields residuals of:

```
56.25 + 5.63*Y + 11.26*X + 5.63*X.*Y - Z
ans =

        0         0.01         0.02         0.03
        0         0.02         0.03         0.05
     0.01         0.03         0.05         0.07
```

Instead, consider the model generated by the regression tool.

```
56.2513 + 11.2497*X + 5.625*Y + 5.625*X.*Y - Z
ans =
       0.0013        0.001       0.0007       0.0004
      -0.0037        0.001      -0.0043       0.0004
       0.0013        0.001       0.0007       0.0004
```

The residuals here are better, but I can do slightly better yet, merely by looking at the coefficients and perturbing them in a logical manner. What does this tell me? That Amadan's model is not the model that originally generated the data, although it was close.

My better model is this one:

```
56.25 + 11.25*X + 5.625*Y + 5.625*X.*Y
ans =
        56.25         67.5        78.75           90
       61.875        78.75       95.625        112.5
         67.5           90        112.5          135
```

See that it is exact, except for two cells which have now been "unrounded". It yields residuals of:

```
56.25 + 11.25*X + 5.625*Y + 5.625*X.*Y - Z
ans =
            0            0            0            0
       -0.005            0       -0.005            0
            0            0            0            0
```

Regression analysis will not always yield the result you need. Sometimes pencil and paper are as good or even better. But it can give you some understanding if you look at the data. My conclusion is that the original model was

```
f(x,y) = 56.25 + 11.25*x + 5.625*y + 5.625*x*y
```

The coefficients are well behaved and simple, and they predict the data perfectly except for two cells, which were surely rounded.

Comment: That is some impressive work, I've never had to do math like this on a table bigger than two columns so I wasn't sure of how to go at it. I'll have to remember Regression Analysis for the next time I have this issue.

Comment: How could I change this so 56.25 defaults to 1,1 (if possible)?

Comment: I spent a few years doing statistical consulting (mostly regression modeling for chemists who needed support) when I was out of school, so I had some practice over the years. I'm not certain I understand your question about the default constant term. Are you asking how to build a model such that the constant term in the model lands at the (1,1) location in the table? If I understand you correctly, this is a problem, as the constant term in a model is the predicted value when x=y=0.

Comment: If your question is how to transform the model such that the constant term is relative to an origin, shifted to the (1,1) coordinate, just substitute x+1 for x, and y+1 for y. That yields f(x,y) = 78.75+11.25*y+16.875*x+5.625*x*y.

Comment: Say I had the same dataset from up top, but 45 is the constant to create the table from, while full integers greater than or equal to 2 are the y axis modifiers, and 0,25,50,75,100 (or .25 steps in percentage) is my x axis modifiers. If 0,1 or 0,0 is 45 can you get the formula? If not, what about 0,0 with 56.25?

I have 2 formulas I got for it but not sure how to merge, not sure if they would be right after merging either: 0.45*x+45 and 5.625*y+45

Answer (score 3):

```
f(x,y) = 56.25 + 5.63 * ((x + 1) * y + 2 * x)
```

And, not programming.

Comment: Closeness? If you mean the numbers aren't exact, your original data is rounded.

Comment: @Amadan Quick Questions: How do you know they are rounded or not? How did you figure it out so fast?

Comment: Well, it could be that the data is really weird. But if you find wet shoeprints, you think a person walked there, and don't think about shoe-wearing cats. The data almost fit what the formula generates; the error is very small, and likely to be the result of rounding. Also, you give all numbers to two decimals. The basic formula should be that; you can play around with the two numbers a bit to see if e.g changing to 5.625 makes more sense (it has a nice sense of symmetry, might well be 5.625, but I didn't test it.)

Comment: @Amadan do you know how the formula would look if the default for x:0,y:0 was 45 and x:1,y:1 was 56.25?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a least squares fit for your data, given an assumed polynomial.  This approach will "work" even if you give it more data points.  Least squares will calculate the polynomial coefficients that minimize the mean square error between the polynomial and the points.